# How to create a shared resource folder in Active Directory to search for text in files using LDAP or any PHP method?

Tags: php, iis, joomla, active-directory

I have joomla and moodle sites that are running on the same IIS server. I use active directory to manage users to authenticate with the sites. My aim is to maintain same users and resources to be used by these sites.

So far I'm able to login users using LDAP in PHP. My next objective is have a common folder that i can upload and manage files to be used by both sites. I want to search for text for example a word or a sentence inside text files and return the results in joomla or moodle using PHP.

How can i achieve this? Share your ideas and sample code in PHP to help me solve this.